# jQuery validation message doesn't show

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I am trying to validate a search bar. When the user leaves the reference field blank and clicks search there should be a message that appears, instead there is no message and my form appears blank. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search').on('click', (function() {
    if ($('#reference').val() == '') {
      // check if form is valid

      $('label[for="ref"]').find('.errorMsg').show();
    } else {
      $('label[for="ref"]').find('.errorMsg').hide();
    };
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="reference">
  <label for="ref">Booking Reference</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="ref" name="Booking Reference Number" class="required" placeholder="12"> <span class="errorMsg">Reference number required</span>

  <button type="button" id="search">Search</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

write simple code using class name like `$('.errorMsg').show();` or `$('.errorMsg').hide();`

and change `id` name `reference` to `ref`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search').on('click', (function(event) {
    if ($('#ref').val() == '') {
      // check if form is valid
      $('.errorMsg').show();
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      $('.errorMsg').hide();
    };
  }));
});
```

```css
.errorMsg {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="reference">
  <label for="ref">Booking Reference</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="ref" name="Booking Reference Number" class="required" placeholder="12"> <span class="errorMsg">Reference number required</span>

  <button type="button" id="search">Search</button>

</form>
```

Comment: So the error message appears now when you click "search" however, the form still appears. Is there any way to stop the form appearing if the errorMsg is shown?

Comment: so you use  `event.preventDefault();` for prevent submitting the `form` @Smith

Comment: Where abouts do I use the event.preventDefault(); at?

Comment: I added it here but it didn't work. 

This is what I have 
$('#search').on('click', (function() {
    if ($('#ref').val() == '') { 
      $(this).prev('.errorMsg').show();
   event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      $(this).prev('.errorMsg').hide();

Comment: what is your exact code and what the problem you rise

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search').on('click', (function() {
    if ($('#ref').val() == '') { 
      $(this).prev('.errorMsg').show();
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      $(this).prev('.errorMsg').hide();
   
    };
  }));
});
 
This is my exact jQuery code. The problem is that when I click search the validation message appears, but so does the form. What I want is when the user has an empty field and clicks search the validation message should appear, but the form should not

Comment: Copied your code, when I click search the validation appears, the form appears as well as the validation in the form

Comment: sorry bro i try my best you can try with another why because i dont understand what you want and i solve your question that you ask  `jQuery validation message doesn't show` and you dont mansion any `form submission` in your question

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you got is [find()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_find.asp) method, wich returns descendant elements of the selected element. In this case are not descendants, if you want use `find()` you must use the form id selector `#reference` like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.errorMsg').hide();
    $("#search").on("click", function(){
        if ($('#ref').val() == '') { 
           $('#reference').find('.errorMsg').show()
         }
         else $('#reference').find('.errorMsg').hide()
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="reference">
  <label for="ref">Booking Reference</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="ref" name="Booking Reference Number" class="required" placeholder="12"> 
  <span class="errorMsg">Reference number required</span>

  <button type="button" id="search">Search</button>

</form>
```

Another way to make it would be use [prev()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_prev.asp) with `this` button:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.errorMsg').hide();
    $("#search").on("click", function(){
        if ($('#ref').val() == '') { 
           $(this).prev('.errorMsg').show();
         }
         else $(this).prev('.errorMsg').hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="reference">
  <label for="ref">Booking Reference</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="ref" name="Booking Reference Number" class="required" placeholder="12"> 
  <span class="errorMsg">Reference number required</span>

  <button type="button" id="search">Search</button>

</form>
```

Comment: What does .prev do?

Comment: Return the previous sibling element, I left you a link on my answer to w3schools, check it.

Comment: Thanks, will check it now

Answer (score 0):

use   $('.errorMsg').show() and  $('.errorMsg').hide() instead of     $('label[for="ref"]').find('.errorMsg').show() and use the correct id to fetch value

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.errorMsg').hide();
  $('#search').on('click', (function() {
    if ($('#ref').val() == '') {
      $('.errorMsg').show();
    } else {
     $('.errorMsg').hide();
    };
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="reference">
  <label for="ref">Booking Reference</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="ref" name="Booking Reference Number" class="required" placeholder="12"> <span class="errorMsg">Reference number required</span>

  <button type="button" id="search">Search</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add a listener for the submit event on the form. This way you will do the validation even if user press enter on the input and you can `preventDefault()` the event, stopping the propagation and the submit

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $form = $('#reference');
  $form.on('submit', function(evt) {
    var $errorMsg = $form.find('.errorMsg');
    if($form.find('#ref').val() == '') {
      $errorMsg.show();
      evt.preventDefault();
    } else {
      $errorMsg.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="reference">
  <label for="ref">Booking Reference</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="ref" name="Booking Reference Number" class="required" placeholder="12">   <span class="errorMsg" style="display:none;">Reference number required</span>

  <button type="submit" id="search">Search</button>

</form>
```